# Hudson Maven build fails using workspace POM, works when pointing to development copy

Tags: build, hudson, maven, pom.xml

I'm developing a series of web applications using Eclipse IDE, Maven, SVN, and Hudson for CI.

When I specify the "Root POM" option in my Hudson job to be the copy of pom.xml in its workspace directory, the build fails citing compilation failure due to missing classpath entries.

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

C:\Users\djones\.hudson\jobs\Store\workspace\trunk\src\main\java\com\app\store\model\User.java:[24,42] package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist

C:\Users\djones\.hudson\jobs\Store\workspace\trunk\src\main\java\com\app\store\dao\UserGroupHibernateSupportDao.java:[8,20] package org.hibernate does not exist

C:\Users\djones\.hudson\jobs\Store\workspace\trunk\src\main\java\com\app\store\dao\UserGroupHibernateSupportDao.java:[10,49] package org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support does not exist
```

When I specify the "Root POM" to be the copy of pom.xml in my Eclipse workspace, it builds just fine. It builds fine from Eclipse too.

I want to move Hudson over to a separate machine so several developers can use it, so I can't very well point to my own development workspace to give it a POM. If I try putting an SVN URL in the "root pom.xml" option, it says file not found.

What *should* I be entering here for a project worked on by several developers, and hosted in an SVN repository?

Comment: Turns out some of the dependencies were set as runtime and not compile, so it was my own fault for not paying attention. I'd still like to know why it worked fine when pointing to my Eclipse workspace copy of the POM though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some of the dependencies were set as runtime and not compile, so it was my own fault for not paying attention. I'd still like to know why it worked fine when pointing to my Eclipse workspace copy of the POM though?